No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation,
Buen día, tengo el siguiente error en mi proyecto, no se cuál es el dll al que debo de hacer referencia, espero puedan ayudarme, estoy usando .Net con ASPX:
 No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 
'Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
 PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' ni una de sus dependencias


Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation he ahí el dll
